# Calculate how many employees changed their position inside company, considering the fact that the employee id stayed the same

Tags: sql

How can I Calculate how many employees changed their position inside company, considering the fact that the employee id stayed the same ?

Comment: do you have a column or a table that show the former position of the employee ?

Answer (score 0):

You just want a count of employees that have more than one position.  A simple method uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having min(position) <> max(position)
     ) i
```

Comment: Id is not a `PK` ??

Comment: @BenS . . . I would suggest you direct the question to the OP.  I wouldn't know except that the question clearly states "the employee id stayed the same" and there is no other "id" column in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select count(*)
from (
select 1 
from table
group by employeeid
having count(*) > 1
) t
```